# 100% height divs with centered content

Tags: css, vertical-alignment, neat

I'm trying to recreate: http://jsfiddle.net/MGRdP/6/

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
}

.table {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    height:100%;
}

.cell {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

using Neat but my divs are not expanding to 100% of the viewport height. Using inspector, I cannot find any discrepancies. Obviously something is off here.

Can someone provide correct markup for neat that allows me to achieve the as the fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

If you want two divs side by side (like the Fiddle), just make each one `width:50%` and `float:left`

```css
html, body{
  height:100%;
}

.table {
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}

.cell {
    border: 2px solid black;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: table-cell;
    height:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="table">
    <div class="cell">
        <p>Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I want the divs to be vertical just like the fiddle, however when i use the neat framework with the above code, i cannot get it to replicate. So my original fiddle and above layout it renders is correct but there is an issue when i try using neat. http://neat.bourbon.io/

Answer (score 0):

```
.table {
    width: 50%;
    display: table;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
}
```

this css make two div to stay side by side.
 You can also use

```
display:inline-block;
vertical-align:top;
width:49%;
```

to make side by side layout;
To center content use `margin:0 auto` for child
and two make height as view port use-

```
height:100vh
```

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/MGRdP/650/)